# Constructor Java

Tags: java, constructor

estoy haciendo un método que calcula el dígito verificador de un código.
por ejemplo 956175/5 (código 956175), (dígito verificador 5). Necesito que por consola me imprima tal cual el código asi 956175/5. Es correcta la forma en como llamo al método calcularDigitoVerificador en el constructor o como tendría que llamarlo??

```
//metodo
public int calcularDigitoVerificador(String codCongreso){
...}

//constructor
public Entrada(String codCongreso) {

    this.codCongreso = codCongreso +"/" + Integer.toString(calcularDigitoVerificador(codCongreso));

    }
```

Comment: En principio, parece que sí; aunque con esa línea de código no estás imprimiendo nada, simplemente almacenando un valor en una variable.  Sería más fácil ayudarte si pudieras proporcionar el código completo o al menos el método ```calcularDigitoVerificador``` para tener un poco más de contexto de qué quieres hacer.

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a implementar una lógica de cálculo en el constructor. Yo dejaría simplemente esto: `this.codCongreso = codCongreso;`  y agragaría un  *getter*  el cual usaría para obtener el `digitoVerificador`  y quizá otro para obtener el dato completo, algo así: `getDigitoVerificador() { /*Calcula y devuelve el DV*/ }` Creo que así la cosa queda más clara y liberas al constructor. Quizá no siempre cuando se crea la instancia del objeto se necesite calcular y/o obtener el dígito verificador.

Comment: Muchas gracias Akamai, A. Cedano

Answer (score 0):

Si el metodo calcularDigitoVerificador te funciona como quieres esto deveria funcionar bien, si hace un poco de ruido el Integer.toString(), lo puedes dejar tal cual:

```
this.codCongreso = codCongreso +"/" + calcularDigitoVerificador(codCongreso);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @dinki93